# C++ Exception Handling

Tags: c++, exception

Can somebody refer me reference book for in depth understanding of C and C++ exception handling mechanisms.

Comment: C has no native exception handling so that book would be pretty short. For C++ you might want to look in the C++-FAQ chapter 17 for starters (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html). I tried googling a bit but couldn't find any books which cover only exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exceptions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fexceptn.htm)

[From Herb Sutter's Guru of the Week](http://gotw.ca/gotw/index.htm)

And the usual culprits More Effective C++ by Scott Myers

C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices By Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu

Answer (score 2):

cannot delete, try to overwrite

Answer (score 1):

The obvious pair of books would be [More] Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter.